Movie about monsters and human sacrifice
I remember when I was a kid, saw a film about two or three men who go to a house where they discover a door to a cave in the basement where there's a tribe of men trying to sacrifice a woman. Also I remember that there were monsters and dinosaurs in the film.
I think the movie was between 1960-1980, color, an American movie. The monsters where made from clay (stop-motion).

Everything you mentioned (the  basement, saving a girl from sacrifice, the stop-motion dinosaurs) is in House II: The Second Story, but it's from 1987.

The new owner of a sinister house gets involved with reanimated corpses and demons searching for an ancient Aztec skull with magic powers.

It was the sequel to the cult film House. Here's the trailer:



